# How to drive XML generation from XSD and rules?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

I am looking for a standard technology to drive the generation of an XML document based on an XSD and a set of rules. Basically I have XSDs that tell me what the XML should look like and what elements are mandatory or optional. What is not in the XSDs is a set of business rules that say things like "if such element's value is this, that other element is actually mandatory" or  "if such element's value is that, that other element should be omitted".

What I have in mind is something that would process the XSDs along with the rules (maybe expressed in something like XPath) and call back my code to generate the mandatory values. The structure of the final document would change dynamically depending on the values of the elements driving the conditions.

I guess I could do something close to what I want with XSLTs. I'd generate all the values with and then use an XSLT to enforce the conditions. But in my case some values maybe take long to produce so I want to avoid computing unnecessary values, meaning values that will be later discarded by the business rules.

Does such a technology exist? FYI I am coding in Java but I am hoping to find a generic technology if possible.

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

The problem you described can probably be handled by Schematron. It can be used with XML Schema, and if you already know XPath and XSLT you won't find it difficult to understand. If can specify complex relationships between unrelated nodes based on values and context beyond the abilities of XML Schema.

The specification and many tutorials you can find in the [Schematron website](http://www.schematron.com/).

Comment: Schematron looks interesting but if I understand it correcty, the rules are used to validate already generated XML. My goal would be to have rules that drive the XML generation. It's not the same but if I end up creating my own generator, I'll probably inspire myself from parts of the schematron language.